# How can I draw a cursor in a custom JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, caret

I have created a rounded `JTextField`, which overwrites the `paintComponent(g: Graphics)` method. The shape and the text are properly painting, but I have not implemented anything that shows a cursor.

> How can I achieve that?

Edit:
super.paintComponent(...) is NOT the solution. If I use that, then you can see the edges of the other painted component.

This is the code so far (as described nothing to render the cursor!)

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    //TODO entfernen
    //super.paintComponent(g);

    if(g instanceof Graphics2D) {
        Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) g;
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        //Draw button background
        graphics.setColor(getBackground());
        graphics.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1, arcRadius, arcRadius);

        this.paintText(graphics);

    }
}

protected final void paintText(@NotNull Graphics2D g) {
    //Draw font
    g.setColor(getForeground());
    if (this.getFont() != null && this.getText() != null) {
        FontMetrics fm = getFontMetrics(getFont());
        g.setColor(this.getForeground());
        g.drawString(this.getText(), ((this.getWidth() / 2) - (fm.stringWidth(this.getText()) / 2)),
                ((this.getHeight() / 2) + fm.getMaxDescent()));
    }
}
```

Edit 2:
Here is the result, when I call super.paintComponent(...):

[image: super component visible]

As you can see, the super component is visible. That is why, I do not call the super method.

Does anybody have experience with Carets? Pretty sure that this is the right way to go...

Comment: I suspect you didn't call super.paintComponent(g) as the first line of your paintComponent method.  Otherwise, it's time to search the Javadoc for JTextField.

Comment: Do you want someone to post a complete code solution of how to create a rounded `JTextField`, or would you like help in correcting your code? If the latter, then I suggest you [edit] your question and post your code. If the former, then I doubt that will happen.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc: you suspect correctly. In fact it's commented out

Comment: Calling super IS WRONG! A second button is painted which shows up in the rounded corners of the custom button.

Comment: Perhaps the following will help? [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

Comment: I didn't notice the corners.  I have poor eyesight.  Change the first fillRoundRect in the paintComponent method to fillRect.  Calling super is never wrong.

Comment: Changed it, still the same result. Well maybe calling super isn't wrong, but isn't it just useless? Because then a button with the setup look-and-feel is drawn and after that I rewrite the buffer with my paintComponent method. That is just writing twice which is time inefficient...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out myself and it is really easy:

Just add

```
this.getCaret().paint(g);
```

to the paintComponent method and the cursor will then be automatically painted.

Answer (score 0):

Calling super.paintComponent(Graphics g) is never wrong!

Unlike the OP, I'll provide a minimal, runnable example showing a custom JTextField with rounded corners.

First, here's the GUI I had to create.

[image: Sample GUI]

As you can see, the yellow custom JTextField has rounded corners.

And here's the minimal, runnable example of what I did.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CustomJTextField implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new CustomJTextField());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Custom JTextField");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 160));

        Font font = panel.getFont().deriveFont(32F);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Something");
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setFont(font);
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.BEFORE_FIRST_LINE);

        QTextField sampleField = new QTextField(panel, 10);
        sampleField.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        sampleField.setFont(font);
        panel.add(sampleField, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class QTextField extends JTextField {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private int arcRadius = 40;

        private Container container;

        public QTextField(Container container, int length) {
            super(length);
            this.container = container;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) g;
            graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

            // Draw button background
            graphics.setColor(container.getBackground());
            graphics.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            graphics.setColor(getBackground());
            graphics.fillRoundRect(20, 20, getWidth() - 40, getHeight() - 40, arcRadius, arcRadius);

            this.paintText(graphics);

        }

        private void paintText(Graphics2D g) {
            // Draw font
            g.setColor(getForeground());
            if (this.getFont() != null && this.getText() != null) {
                FontMetrics fm = getFontMetrics(getFont());
                g.setColor(this.getForeground());
                g.drawString(this.getText(), ((this.getWidth() / 2) - (fm.stringWidth(this.getText()) / 2)),
                        ((this.getHeight() / 2) + fm.getMaxDescent()));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: yes, I know. I changed exactly that. The super button is still visible and funny enough the cursor isn't visible in you custom button either. Why is that?

Comment: @F_Schmidt:  You're going to have to get the caret position and paint a cursor yourself.  You surprised me by forcing entry into the center of the text field.  Everything these guys do, you're going to have to do.  http://developer.classpath.org/doc/javax/swing/JTextField-source.html

Comment: oh gosh. That was what I expected. Do you have any idea how I can paint a cursor? I have no idea where to start.